# Java Generics methods - using for the first time

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to use a generic method for the first time and am somewhat confused.  I created a simple example to demonstrate that I am probably going about this the wrong way and need straightening out.   I am using Eclipse 3.6.1.  I was under the impression that the compiler determined the argument types through inference, but am not sure why it is forcing me use casting in the generic method.  This is a simple example.

```
class Test1 
{
    Test1 () {};
    public String getX () {return "Test1"};
};

class Test2 
{
    Test2 () {};
    public String getX () {return "Test2"};
};
```

my main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    Test1 tst1 = new Test1();
    Test2 tst2 = new Test2();

    System.out.println("result: " + displayTest(tst1, tst2));
}

static <T,S> boolean displayTest(T x, S y)
{
    System.out.println("X: " + ((Test1) x).getX());
    System.out.println("Y: " + ((Test2) y).getX());

    if (((Test1) x).getX().equals(((Test2) y).getX()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I thought the compiler would know that `T` in this case was an instance of `Test1` and `S` was `Test2`, yet in Eclipse, `getX` is not a valid method.  In order to get this to compile, it forces me to cast the objects to the correct type, which seems to me to be against the general principles of a generic method.

Obviously, I am not getting this and am doing something wrong.  How does the compiler know what the types are in the generic method then ?  How should something like this be done ?  In my large system where I am trying to implement this, I have several methods that operate on different types of objects and am trying to make them generic.  i.e.  Method 1 calls Method 2 (which uses the generic type), which in turn calls Method 3 (again passing the generic types).  I was hoping only the start of the function calls (calling of method 1 in this case) needed to know what type the objects were and all subsequent methods were just generic methods.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does not know the types inside the method. They can be anything.

If you use `<T extends Y>`, where `Y` is an interface defining `getY()`, it would work.

The point of generics is to ensure compile-time safety. They are mainly a compile-time notion. For example:

```
public static <T> T instantiate(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

This method can be used, without any cases, like this:

```
Foo foo = instantiate(Foo.class);
Bar bar = instantiate(Bar.class);
```

---

Another example, from the Collections framework. There is `Collections.enumeration(collection)`, which is generic. So:

```
Enumeration<String> enumeration1 = 
      Collections.enumeration(new ArrayList<String>(..));
Enumeration<Integer> enumeration2 = 
      Collections.enumeration(new ArrayList<Integer>(..));
```

No casts, but you are certain that these will be the types. And then the `nextElement()` method will return either `String` or `Integer`, without the need to cast:

```
String s = enumeration1.nextElement();
Integer i = enumeration2.nextElement();
```

---

Without generics, you would need to use casts in these examples, and if you have passed the wrong argument, you would get a runtime exception (most likely a `ClassCastException`). With generics you get the exception at compile-time.

The compiler actually adds these casts on your behalf, but only after it is certain that the cast can't go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at compile time the compiler does not know the concrete type of `T` and `S`. Your main method calls `displayTest` with concrete instances of `Test1` and `Test2`, but there's nothing stopping you from calling it with, say, a `String` and an `Integer`.

This means that you can't call `getX` on `x` because you can't guarantee that `T` is a subclass of `Test1`.

You **can** constrain the type of `T` and `S` with captures:

```
boolean <T extends Test1, S extends Test2> displayTest(T x, S y)
```

This tells the compiler that `T` must be a `Test1` (or a subclass of `Test1`) which means you don't need to cast.

Comment: Ah, Ok.  I get it now.  Like I said, first time using generics.  Thanks for all the quick responses....

Answer (score 0):

Why would the compiler know that T and S are Test1 and Test2? You can call displayTest from anywhere in your code, any number of times with any number of different object types. What is it supposed to do there?

Also, eclipse != compiler. Eclipse's code completion doesn't "compile" anything. The compiler knows exactly what types are being put in there, but only for each CALL to that function. That's why it's called generic. It can take any generic type.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the compiler determines the argument types through inference, it means something different than what you are thinking.

Since displayMethod is a generic method, the "proper" way to call the method is to tell the compiler what T and S stand for in this particular method call by calling it as

`ClassName.<Test1,Test2>displayMethod(tst1,tst2)`

But since java is smart, the compiler can infer w/o you telling it exactly what T and S, that T and S are going to be Test1 and Test2 if you just do,

`ClassName.displayMethod(tst1, tst2)`

Also, like cameron skinner said, you can fix your code by making T extend Test1 and S extend Test2. Another fix that you can do is leave `<T, S>` as it is, and renaming your `getX()` method to the override the `toString()` method. Since `toString()` is a member of the `Object` class, the generic classes `T and S` will have access to it and you won't need to restrict your method to only accept arguments which are of type `Test1 and Test2`

Comment: it didn't work because T and S don't have access to getX(). That is a completely different problem entirely. INFERENCE allows the compiler to infer the type of classes in the method call. But the generic types T and S must have access to all the method that you are calling on T and S. Since, T and S are generic types and thus of type Object, they don't have access to getX()

Comment: Yea, certainly did not think of that.   In my case, however, I need access to multiple methods in the objects, so overloading the toString() would not work for this case.  However, I just realized that I do need to constrain both T and S, but I need either of them to be able to be Test1 or Test2 in this case.  How would I go about that ?

Comment: So, the two ways you can fix your code is by either changing to <T extends Test1, S extends Test2> or by renaming getX() to override the toString() method

Comment: Rather than speaking in Test1 and Test2 terms, can you tell me specifically the real problem you are working on? because the way i would implement the Test1 and Test2 is very different from yours

Comment: I have the T extends Test1 working, but as I just posted, need either of them to be able to be either one.  Thanks.

Comment: If that is the case, you can have an interface called ITest and have your Test1 and Test2 realize the interface. Then you can change <T, S> to <T extends ITest> (only need it once since the 2 types are gonna be the same).

Comment: but keep in mind that your two variables tst1 and tst2 would have to be of type ITest and not Test1 and Test2

Comment: Rather difficult to explain but will try.  just that the different objects are created in different areas of the app and house the same kind of data, but from differing sources.  they share the same method calls.  stuck with this design.  hard to explain.

Comment: just didnt want to overload all the validation methods to accept two diff kinds of objects, when they really do the same thing

Comment: if they share the same method calls, try using an interface with the method call, that way all the objects can share the same type.

Comment: yes, I'm going to put together a little sample first.  Thanks for all your help.  Light bulbs really went off.

Comment: yep, that works.  just constrained to the interface.  passed in my normal objects tst1 and 2.  didn't have to be type IGeneric